# Using a loop to update info for a new widget using tkinter

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, tkinter

I am now trying to write a UI on python using Tkinter. At the first try, the python works just fine. But I found that when Tkinter is in the mainloop, it won't do the for loop when the button is pressed.

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk

# read the food info
csvfile = open('Foodinfo.csv', newline='', encoding="utf-8")
rows = csv.reader(csvfile)

# create the gui
root = tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=900, height=1300)
canvas1.create_window(400, 200, window=tkinter.ttk.Separator(canvas1, orient='vertical').grid(row=0, column=2))

# get all the info of the ingredient
count=0
for row in rows:
    # all the info are on the second row of the csv
    if count==1:
        row=str(row)
        data = row.split(",")
        nutrition = []
        unit = []
        for nu in data[1::]:
            if len(nu)>=2:
                # if the info has units
                if '(' in nu:
                    nutrition.append(nu[2:nu.index('(')])
                    tmp = nu[::-1]
                    unit.append(nu[len(nu)-tmp.index('('):-2])
                else:
                    nutrition.append(nu[2:-1])
        break
    count+=1

# get the food info the user wants to know
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="The food Info you want to know")
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(400, 200, window=label1.grid(row=0, column=2))
#label1.grid(row=0, column=2)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
# canvas1.create_window(200, 50, window=entry1)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=2)
canvas1.create_window(200, 25, window=entry1.grid(row=1, column=2))

def nutrition_Select():
    selection=[]
    for i in checkboxes:
        if checkboxes[i].get()==True:
            selection.append(nutrition[i])
    food = entry1.get()
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
    newWindow.geometry("750x250")
    count = 0
    # the for loop is here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    for row in rows:
            if row[2]==food or row[3]==food:
                found=row
                for x in selection:
                    if x in nutrition:
                        if nutrition.index(x)>=5:
                            tk.Label(newWindow, text=x+" "+row[nutrition.index(x)+1]+" "+unit[nutrition.index(x)-4], font='helvetica').grid(row=count)
                        else:
                            tk.Label(newWindow, text=x+" "+row[nutrition.index(x)+1], font='helvetica').grid(row=count)
                    count+=1

checkboxes = {}
for i in range(len(nutrition)-1):
    checkboxes[i] = tk.BooleanVar()
    Cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=nutrition[i], variable=checkboxes[i])
    Cb.grid(row=i//5+2, column=(i%5))
    # canvas1.create_window(100+100*(i%8),75+50*(i//8), window=Cb)

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", width=10, command=nutrition_Select)
btn.grid(row=24, column=2)

# used to loop the window
root.mainloop()
# close the csv after using
csvfile.close()
```

These are the screenshot from my program.

[The first time I try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO74n.jpg)

[The new window shows the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnUbu.jpg)

[After I changed the checkbox or the entry box and clicked enter again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j3Zz.jpg)

[Nothing shows on the new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFQUk.jpg)

Is there a solution for this problem? I'm stuck.

I tried to search the net for this problem, but most of the answers indicates that a for loop won't work in the mainloop, because that will cause mainloop to malfunction. So I'd like to ask if there is a solution for this problem, or suggest another way to deal with this issue.

Comment: Which loop are you trying to run more than once? If it's either of the two loops that *aren't* inside the `nutrition_Select()` function, you'll also need to wrap them in their own functions as well so they can be called more than once.

Comment: Why are you calling `canvas1.create_window(..., window=<tkinter object>.grid(...))`. This makes no sense. Please look at how `<tkinter.Canvas>.create_window` works. Also please create a [mre].

Comment: @JRiggles it is the for loop in the ```nutrition_Select()``` function

Comment: @TheLizzard I am trying to use ```tk.Entry``` to get something from the user and trigger the for loop with ```tk.button```, then generates a new widget to show the result. However, the for loop only works at the first time, if I've changed the input, nothing shows on the new widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem can be solved by calling the csv everytime when I want to search the information I want.